# Is there a way to find the oldest file in a directory using Azure Data Lake?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way to find the oldest file in a directory using Azure Data Lake?

I had assumed I could use the meta data activity to get all the file names and dates (which I can). I then thought I could use the forEach to set two variables in the pipeline (Name & Date) with the values from the list if they were older than the current value of the variables. This does not work as all the files are processed in parallel. This really should not be this hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ForEach activity in Azure Data Factory works in parallel by default , but you change to work sequentially through checking Sequential option.

[image]

More details, you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#type-properties).